# How to properly use Gorm auto increment?

Tags: database, rest, go, auto-increment, go-gorm

I have a Go struct that defines a table managed by `gorm`.  It includes a unique, integer, primary key that auto increments.

```
type CreatedSurvey struct {
    ...
    Id int `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true;unique"`
    ...
}
```

Every `CreatedSurvey` object  has its own unique `Id` and it is created from a template which has its own unique template `Id` (`SurveyTemplateId`) field that can be used to trace the created object back to its template.  When the front-end application calls an API endpoint that triggers the creation of a new `CreatedSurvey`, it provides all of the information from the template, including this template `SurveyTemplateId`.  And initially, this `SurveytemplateId` was marshalled to the `CreatedSurvey` `Id` field.  For an `Id` of 0, this caused no issues when `MyDb.DB.Create(&survey)` is called, the `autoIncrement` functions properly.  However, if the provided `Id` field is `> 0`, `autoIncrement` doesn't take place, and because of the primary key nature of the attribute, a conflict can cause errors.

To avoid this issue, I have been setting the value of the `Id` to `0` explicitly after the `JSON` has been marshalled.

```
    var createdSurvey surveys.CreatedSurvey
    err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&createdSurvey)
    if err != nil {
        restErr := errors.NewBadRequestError("invalid json body")
        ctx.JSON(restErr.Status, restErr)
        return
    }
    createdSurvey.Id = 0
```

This avoids any issues on creation.

```
result := users_db.DB.Create(&survey)
```

This works, but it doesn't look clean and doesn't seem to fit in with the general cleanliness of `Go`.

Should I be using `gorm` differently?  Or is this the best option?

Comment: You should generally not use the id field to track something else. If it is not necessary to track which template the survey was created from, just don't propagate the id, otherwise use a separate field that indicates which template was used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
type CreatedSurvey struct {
...
Id uint64 `json:"id" sql:"AUTO_INCREMENT" gorm:"primary_key"`
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type User struct {
gorm.Model
Id        uint      `json:"id" gorm:"unique;primaryKey;autoIncrement"`
Name      string    `json:"name"`
Username  string    `json:"username" gorm:"unique"`
Email     string    `json:"email" gorm:"unique"`
Password  string    `json:"password"`
CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt" `
```

}